# -fprofile-dir tag in GCOV utility

Tags: gcov

I want to store my *.gcda and *.gcno files generated after compiling the programs with GCOV flags and running the executable.
I am using the -fprofile-arcs , -ftest-coverage flags.
I am also using the -fprofile-dir flag and setting it with the path at which I want to store my *.gcda and *.gcno files. Am I doing right?
But I am not getting the path in the right folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your .gcno files are generated only in the directory where your source files are, but to generate .gcda files at a different location you can use -fprofile-generate="PATH" flag.

Comment: .gcno files are generated in the directory where your object files are. This may or may not be the same as the directory where your sources are.