# GCOV - gcda file generated in different folder

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcov

Folder structure
~/sandbox/dev
~/sandbox/test

1. I have main.cpp in dev directory. I compiled the code using --coverage flag to generate code coverage.
   Now a.out and main.gcno files are generated.
2. Now I copy main.cpp, main.gcno and a.out to test directory
3. When I run the a.out from test directory, the main.gcda file is generated at the dev folder instead of current working directory.

It seems like the path is hardcoded in the binary/gcno.
What changes are required so that the gcda file will be generated in test directory ?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a late answer - but you can use environment variables `GCOV_PREFIX` and `GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP` to direct the .gcda files to some other path.

You *do* need to copy (or link) the .gcno files and .gcda files to the same directory in order to run gcov, though.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, the .gcda files are also stored in the same directory as the object file, but the GCC `-fprofile-dir` option may be used to store the .gcda files in a separate directory.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-Data-Files.html

[-fprofile-dir tag in GCOV utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710598/fprofile-dir-tag-in-gcov-utility)